# How to use docker-machine to create docker host with alpine instead of boot2docker?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, boot2docker

Is it possible to change the default linux distribution when create docker host with `docker-machine create` command ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the specific option depends on what "driver" you're using; for AWS, for instance, there's a `--amazonec2-ami` option to specify the AMI (Amazon Machine Image ID) to use.  There's a listing of all of the backend drivers and the corresponding options [in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/os-base/).  Looking around there, there isn't an especially exhaustive list of available images around, so you might have to do some more research.

That having been said, nothing forces you to use Docker Machine to get a VM with Docker on it: you can provision a VM or cloud instance with whatever technique you feel comfortable with and install Docker on that in the usual way.  If you want to run things besides Docker on the system and have strong opinions about the host distribution, it might be better to skip the small amount of automation Docker Machine gives you to gain that control.